# Creating a bump function on a spline region

Tags: function-construction, regions, splines

For a presentation, I'd like to include a 3D plot of a function of two variables x,y with the properties that (a) it looks "smooth" i.e. without jagged edges and (b) has support equal to a given smooth domain R.

**Ideally** I would want to have some flexibility in what R could be - say, a region whose boundary is a given BSplineCurve.

Any ideas how to represent the interior of a spline curve as a region, or, once this is done, how to define the function with the desired properties?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Some example code for the `BSplineCurve` would encourage folks to copy/paste it into their *Mathematica* to try out their ideas for a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
  ParametricPlot[
   BSplineFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, .5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
     SplineClosed -> True][t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[Sin[6 x y], {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics was a very helpful function.  I was able to take it from there.  The following code achieved what I wanted:

```
boundaryPoints={{0, 0}, {4, 4}, {8, 1}, {12, 0}, {8, -1}, {4, -4}};
bsc = BSplineFunction[boundaryPoints,SplineClosed->True];
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @ ParametricPlot[bsc[t],{t,0,1}];
regBdry = RegionBoundary[reg];
f[x_,y_]:=RegionDistance[regBdry,{x,y}];
Plot3D[f[x,y]^2,{x,y} ∈ reg]
```

[image: My desired bump function]